# Проверка класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на кнопку я задаю значение переменной i, и создаю класс с названием item+i, но при проверке на наличие такого проходит только первый класс item1, остальные классы не находит, и создаёт повторно блоки. Как можно это исправить?

```
  <script>
  var i = 0;
  </script>
  <script>
      $(".buyprod").click(function () {
        var img = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
        if ($('#cart_item').hasClass('item'+i)) {
          document.getElementById('input'+i).value += 1;
        }
        else{
          $("#cartdiv").append('<div id="cart_item" class="item'+i+'"><div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item"><img src="'+ img +'" alt="photo1"><br><p><input id="input'+i+'" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="5" step="1"></div></div></div>');
          alert(i);
          }
      });
  </script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center" style="background:black;color:white;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 tovitem">
        <h2>Товар 1</h2>
        <img src="img/1t.png" alt="tovar" class="img-fluid" style="float:right;">
        <p>Описание товара</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info buyprod" type="button" name="button" onclick="i=1">Buy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 tovitem">
        <h2>Товар 2</h2>
        <img src="img/2t.png" alt="tovar" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Описание товара</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info buyprod" type="button" name="button" onclick="i=2">Buy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 tovitem">
        <h2>Товар 3</h2>
        <img src="img/3t.png" alt="tovar" class="img-fluid">
        <p>Описание товара</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info buyprod" type="button" name="button" onclick="i=3">Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('.item'+i).length) {
```

И не создавайте элементы с одинаковыми `id`.

---

```js
var i = 3;
document.getElementById('input' + i).value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input' + i).value, 10) + 1;
```

```html
<input id="input3" value="100"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а что именно Вы здесь проверяете? length это что?

Comment: @Alexander Проверяется наличие элементов с таким классом.

Comment: Спасибо, а Вы не подскажете как перевести значение input в число, document.getElementById('input'+i).value += parseInt(document.getElementById('input'+i).value,10)+1; записывает пустое поле в input

Comment: @Alexander Не используйте `+=`.